# I am having trouble getting my code to loop

Tags: java

The code below should loop to produce:

```
It should print  1: Lather and Rinse
                 2: Lather and Rinse
                 Done.

It produces:
                 1: Lather and Rinse
                    Done.
```

---

```
   import java.util.Scanner;

public class ShampooMethod {

   public static void printShampooInstructions(int numCycles) {

       if (numCycles < 1) {
        System.out.println("Too few.");
        return;
    } 
    else if (numCycles > 4) {
        System.out.println ("Too many.");
       return;
    } 

    else {

       for (int i = 1; i <= numCycles; i++) {
       System.out.print(+ i);
       System.out.println(": Lather and rinse.");
       System.out.println("Done.");
       return;
    }

    }
}  

   public static void main (String [] args) {
      printShampooInstructions(2);

      return;
   }
}
```

Comment: remove the last `return ` from `printShampooInstructions` will work as you expected

Answer (score 2):

You have to remove the `return;` statement otherwise your loop will stop in first pass

```
for (int i = 1; i <= numCycles; i++) {
   System.out.print(i); // no need of +
   System.out.println(": Lather and rinse.");
   //return; //remove this
}
System.out.println("Done.");
```

Answer (score 1):

You `return` inside the loop, so the method exits the first time through. Remove the `return`.

Also, it's not really a good practice to declare variables inline. Put your declaration at the start of the method and just initialize it in the `for` statement.

Answer (score 0):

The **return** statement will immediately cause the method to return, therefore the loop will stop on first pass. Remove the return statement from your loop and it shall work.

Comment: Thank you all for the assistance. Removing the return worked.